# My search function/form isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a searchbar/function, whether it be in Vanilla JS or jQuery. I have created an input:

```
<div id="searchbar">  
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</div>
```

I have tried a number of possible solutions to get this to work, but none of them worked out.

```
var searchField = document.getElementById('searchbar');

searchField.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var search = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
    console.log(search);
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++){
        if (data.results[i].title.search(search) != -1|| data.results[i].summary.search(search) != -1){
            result.push(data.results[i]);
            document.getElementById('searchbar').innerHTML = " ";
        };
    }});
```

But it doesnt seem to work. All i need it to do is, be able to go through the API from the NY-Times, and show me the result.

Comment: Please define `doesnt seem to work`

Comment: there is one `</div>` tag too much

Comment: also #searchbar doesn't contain the value, you should  get the input in your `var searchField`

Comment: Where is your actual query to the API?

Comment: your id="searchbar" is a div, the value, the kyup etc should be on the input field, try adding the id to the input instead of the div

Comment: `data.results` is undefined .is not there in the snippet

Comment: you miss to do the query in your code. So there is nothing to fetch and display